# How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory-listing

I'm trying to get a list of the names of all the files present in a directory using Node.js.  I want output that is an array of filenames. How can I do this?

Comment: `fs.readdir` works, but cannot use file name glob patterns like `ls /tmp/*core*`.  Check out **https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob**.  Globs can even search in sub-directories.

Comment: Checkout NPM's `readdir-recursive` module though if you're looking for the names of files in subdirectories also

Comment: [es7 method with await here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37532027/124486)

Comment: fs.readdir is a simple async solution - examples [here](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/fs/readdir)

Comment: Still not answer using an iterator? I've 2.5 millions of files to scan… I do not want to get a list of 2.5m of path after 10 minutes.

Comment: @FlavienVolken, you are looking for https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dir_read

Comment: @undefined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298994/is-there-any-directory-walker-in-ts-js-using-an-async-iterator

Comment: Year 2022 - Read the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options

Answer (score 2148, accepted):

You can use the [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback) or [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) methods. `fs` is included in Node.js core, so there's no need to install anything.

**fs.readdir**

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

**fs.readdirSync**

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

The difference between the two methods, is that the first one is asynchronous, so you have to provide a callback function that will be executed when the read process ends.

The second is synchronous, it will return the file name array, but it will stop any further execution of your code until the read process ends.

Comment: Note: `readdir` also shows *directory names*. To filter these, use [`fs.stat(path, callback(err, stats))`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.stat) and [`stats.isDirectory()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.Stats).

Comment: I should add that most probably you should go with readdire because you dont want to block IO in node.

Comment: @user3705055 unless you're using gulp to read in a directory of source order dependant files and compile them into a single executable.

Comment: For the [newer promise method see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37532027/124486).

Comment: I'm confused... Wouldn't it be better to use `ls` or `dir /b/s` for this job? Would have thought these methods would be much faster than iterating in Node...

Comment: @Sancarn You want to try parsing the output of `ls`? Just wait until somebody creates some filenames with embedded spaces and newlines…

Comment: @RadonRosborough yeah recently found out that `ls` isn't really good for file lists. But `find` is pretty good at it :)

Comment: As of Node v10.10.0, a combination of the `withFileTypes` option for the `readdir` and `readdirSync` functions and the `isDirectory()` method can be used to filter just the files in the directory - [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) and an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439981/1616963)

Comment: How would you do this in Typescript?
I get this error when I try to do in typescript: "TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function"
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the `readdirSync` I push the `file` into my array I defined in first line of the class. In the `readdirSync` the array size is 1 but, out of that scope, the size is 0!

Answer (score 276):

IMO the most convenient way to do such tasks is to use a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) tool. Here's a [glob package](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for node.js. Install with

```
npm install glob
```

Then use wild card to match filenames (example taken from package's [website](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob))

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

If you are planning on using [globby](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) here is an example to look for any xml files that are under current folder

```js
var globby = require('globby');

const paths = await globby("**/*.xml");
```

Comment: this was the best solution for me as i wanted to specify filetype easier than string comparisons. Thanks.

Comment: I like this one too just because globbing is almost a fundamental skill in node. If you want to just get filenames back, pass in a `cwd` in the options object.

Comment: How can get the results of `glob` outside of itself? Eg. I want to `console.log` the results, but not inside `glob()`?

Comment: @Lanti: The `glob.sync(pattern, [options])` method may be easier to use as it simply returns an array of file names, rather than using a callback. More info here: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Comment: For people like me looking for a glob implementation using Promises, check out globby by sindresorhus: https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby

Comment: I have updated the answer with @NachoColoma coment and showing how to use it

Answer (score 206):

As of Node v10.10.0, it is possible to use the new `withFileTypes` option for [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) in combination with the [`dirent.isDirectory()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_isdirectory) function to filter for filenames in a directory. That looks like this:

```
fs.readdirSync('./dirpath', {withFileTypes: true})
.filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
.map(item => item.name)
```

The returned array is in the form:

```
['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
```

Comment: this is what people are searching for in 2020 - should be "pinned"

Comment: And 2022 as well!

Comment: Excellent, this answers the question with regards to `names of the files`

Answer (score 192):

The answer above does not perform a recursive search into the directory though. Here's what I did for a recursive search (using [node-walk](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk): `npm install walk`)

```
var walk    = require('walk');
var files   = [];

// Walker options
var walker  = walk.walk('./test', { followLinks: false });

walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    // Add this file to the list of files
    files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
});

walker.on('end', function() {
    console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: fs.readdirSync is better, native alternative created specially for this.

Comment: fs.readdirSync doesn't walk into sub directories unfortunately, unless you are willing to write your own routine to do just that, which you don't given that there are already npm modules out there to solve this very problem.

Comment: Here is a link to the walk github repo + docs:
https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk

Comment: OP did not ask about which API does a recursive read. In any case, the accepted answer provides what can also serve as a basis for making a recursive read.

Comment: This is a fantastic function. Quick question: is there a quick way to ignore certain dirs? I want to ignore directories starting with `.git`

Comment: For the [newer ES7 method see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37532027/124486).

Comment: > unless you are willing to write your own routine to do just that, which you don't given that there are already npm modules out there to solve this very problem

Yeah, you don't want to write left-pad yourself too when there's a package for that! :/

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: @RubenTan How to check the filetype? Cause it lists hidden files too. On mac: .DS_Store, for example.

Answer (score 129):

Get files in all subdirs

```
const fs=require('fs');

function getFiles (dir, files_){
    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (var i in files){
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else {
            files_.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
}

console.log(getFiles('path/to/dir'))
```

Comment: Why `if (typeof files_ === 'undefined') files_=[];`? you only need to do `var files_ = files_ || [];` instead of `files_ = files_ || [];`.

Comment: You forgot to add `var fs = require('fs');` at the start of `getFiles`.

Comment: This is a recursive method. It does not support very deep folder structures, which will result in a Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen If you've got a file system nested 11k directories deep you've probably got a lot of other things to worry about :p

Comment: It doesn't have to be 11k. It depends on how much is put on the stack, and this method has quite large allocations to the stack.

Answer (score 79):

Here's a simple solution using only the native `fs` and `path` modules:

```
// sync version
function walkSync(currentDirPath, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');
    fs.readdirSync(currentDirPath).forEach(function (name) {
        var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            callback(filePath, stat);
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walkSync(filePath, callback);
        }
    });
}
```

or async version (uses `fs.readdir` instead):

```
// async version with basic error handling
function walk(currentDirPath, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');
    fs.readdir(currentDirPath, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
        files.forEach(function (name) {
            var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
            var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
            if (stat.isFile()) {
                callback(filePath, stat);
            } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                walk(filePath, callback);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then you just call (for sync version):

```
walkSync('path/to/root/dir', function(filePath, stat) {
    // do something with "filePath"...
});
```

or async version:

```
walk('path/to/root/dir', function(filePath, stat) {
    // do something with "filePath"...
});
```

The difference is in how node blocks while performing the IO. Given that the API above is the same, you could just use the async version to ensure maximum performance.

However there is one advantage to using the synchronous version. It is easier to execute some code as soon as the walk is done, as in the next statement after the walk. With the async version, you would need some extra way of knowing when you are done. Perhaps creating a map of all paths first, then enumerating them. For simple build/util scripts (vs high performance web servers) you could use the sync version without causing any damage.

Comment: Should replace the line in `walkSync` from `walk(filePath, callback);` to `walkSync(filePath, callback);`

Comment: But you're still using fs.statSync, which blocks, in async version. Shouldn't you be using fs.stat instead?

Answer (score 28):

## Using Promises with ES7

### Asynchronous use with mz/fs

The [`mz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz) module provides promisified versions of the core node library. Using them is simple. First install the library...

```
npm install mz
```

Then...

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
fs.readdir('./myDir').then(listing => console.log(listing))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Alternatively you can write them in asynchronous functions in ES7:

```
async function myReaddir () {
  try {
    const file = await fs.readdir('./myDir/');
  }
  catch (err) { console.error( err ) }
};
```

### Update for recursive listing

Some of the users have specified a desire to see a recursive listing (though not in the question)... Use [`fs-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise). It's a thin wrapper around [`mz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz).

```
npm install fs-promise;
```

then...

```
const fs = require('fs-promise');
fs.walk('./myDir').then(
    listing => listing.forEach(file => console.log(file.path))
).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: fs.walk is removed from fs-promise as it it not supported by fs ( https://github.com/kevinbeaty/fs-promise/issues/28 )

Answer (score 24):

## non-recursive version

You don't say you want to do it recursively so I assume you only need direct children of the directory.

Sample code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdirSync('your-directory-path')
  .filter((file) => fs.lstatSync(path.join(folder, file)).isFile());
```

Answer (score 23):

**Dependencies.**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
```

**Definition.**

```
// String -> [String]
function fileList(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce(function(list, file) {
    var name = path.join(dir, file);
    var isDir = fs.statSync(name).isDirectory();
    return list.concat(isDir ? fileList(name) : [name]);
  }, []);
}
```

**Usage.**

```
var DIR = '/usr/local/bin';

// 1. List all files in DIR
fileList(DIR);
// => ['/usr/local/bin/babel', '/usr/local/bin/bower', ...]

// 2. List all file names in DIR
fileList(DIR).map((file) => file.split(path.sep).slice(-1)[0]);
// => ['babel', 'bower', ...]
```

Please note that `fileList` is way too optimistic. For anything serious, add some error handling.

Comment: I added an `excludeDirs` array argument also. It changes it enough so that maybe you should edit it instead (if you want it). Otherwise I'll add it in a different answer. https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/f3f221b4fb86b4375650

Comment: @AT Nice! You should post your own answer, as it's a useful extension. Let's keep this one featureless.

Comment: this will cause an error if your input is a directory where you get /Users/user/Desktop/project/example/Users/user/Desktop/project/example/constraints.txt

Answer (score 20):

I'm assuming from your question that you don't want directories names, just files.

#### Directory Structure Example

```
animals
├── all.jpg
├── mammals
│   └── cat.jpg
│   └── dog.jpg
└── insects
    └── bee.jpg
```

#### `Walk` function

Credits go to [Justin Maier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616888/justmaier) in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/8691344#gistcomment-2927279)

If you want *just an array* of the files paths use `return_object: false`:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

async function walk(dir) {
    let files = await fs.readdir(dir);
    files = await Promise.all(files.map(async file => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
        if (stats.isDirectory()) return walk(filePath);
        else if(stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    }));

    return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}
```

#### Usage

```js
async function main() {
   console.log(await walk('animals'))
}
```

#### Output

```js
[
  "/animals/all.jpg",
  "/animals/mammals/cat.jpg",
  "/animals/mammals/dog.jpg",
  "/animals/insects/bee.jpg"
];
```

Comment: @justmaier & a.barbieri - thanks for the code and answer!

Comment: hi if i want to show folder as well so what should i do ?
like
`
[
  "/animals/all.jpg",
  "/animals/mammals"
  "/animals/mammals/cat.jpg",
  "/animals/mammals/dog.jpg",
  "/animals/insects/bee.jpg"
];
`

any solution

Comment: Hi @Aakash, try adding `files.unshift(dir)` berfore the last `return` of the async function. Anyway it'd be best if you could create a new question as it might help other people with the same need and receive better feedback. ;-)

Comment: hi @a.barbieri what if i want to read only starting 2 level folder what i have to do for ex: my directory look like this `animals/mammals/name` and i want to stop at mammal by providing some depth `[ "/animals/all.jpg", "/animals/mammals/cat.jpg", "/animals/mammals/dog.jpg", "/animals/insects/bee.jpg" ];`

Comment: Please create a new question and copy/paste the link it here in the comments. I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 16):

its just 2 lines of code:

```
fs=require('fs')
fs.readdir("./img/", (err,filename)=>console.log(filename))
```

Image:
[image: aakash4dev]

Answer (score 15):

if someone still search for this, i do this:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const getAllFiles = dir =>
    fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce((files, file) => {
        const name = path.join(dir, file);
        const isDirectory = fs.statSync(name).isDirectory();
        return isDirectory ? [...files, ...getAllFiles(name)] : [...files, name];
    }, []);
```

and its work very good for me

Comment: Worked great for me AND it's recursive. Just remember that the import syntax is still behind a flag in Node, you might have to go the old way: const fs = require('fs');

Comment: @Josh It works like charm. However, having a bit of difficulty to understand how the `[...files, ...getAllFiles(name)]` or `[...files, name]` works. A bit of explanation would be very helpful :)

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan The `...` used here is called a spread syntax. What it basically does is takes all objects inside the array and 'spreads' it into the new array. In this case, all entries inside the `files` array is added to the return along with all the values returned from the recursive call. YOu can refer to the spread syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 14):

Load `fs`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Read files *async*:

```
fs.readdir('./dir', function (err, files) {
    // "files" is an Array with files names
});
```

Read files *sync*:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync('./dir');
```

Answer (score 13):

My one liner code:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = 'somePath/'

const filesArray = fs.readdirSync(path).filter(file => fs.lstatSync(path+file).isFile())
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what the code does and how it helps the OP?

Comment: It simply gets an array of file names from some path. Only names of files, not subdirectory names.

Answer (score 9):

Get `sorted` filenames. You can filter results based on a specific `extension` such as `'.txt'`, `'.jpg'` and so on.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as Path from 'path';

function getFilenames(path, extension) {
    return fs
        .readdirSync(path)
        .filter(
            item =>
                fs.statSync(Path.join(path, item)).isFile() &&
                (extension === undefined || Path.extname(item) === extension)
        )
        .sort();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

My 2 cents if someone:

*Just want to list file names (excluding directories) from a local sub-folder on their project*

- ✅ No additional dependencies
- ✅ 1 function
- ✅ Normalize path (Unix vs. Windows)

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

/**
 * @param {string} relativeName "resources/foo/goo"
 * @return {string[]}
 */
const listFileNames = (relativeName) => {
  try {
    const folderPath = path.join(process.cwd(), ...relativeName.split("/"));
    return fs
      .readdirSync(folderPath, { withFileTypes: true })
      .filter((dirent) => dirent.isFile())
      .map((dirent) => dirent.name.split(".")[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

```
README.md
package.json
resources
 |-- countries
    |-- usa.yaml
    |-- japan.yaml
    |-- gb.yaml
    |-- provinces
       |-- .........


listFileNames("resources/countries") #=> ["usa", "japan", "gb"]
```

Comment: You have the problem where `path` is the name of your imported `require('path')` but then you re-define `const path` inside the function... This is really confusing and might lead to bugs!

Answer (score 8):

Try this, it works for me

```js
import fs from "fs/promises";

const path = "path/to/folder";

export const readDir = async function readDir(path) {

    const files = await fs.readdir(path);

    // array of file names
    console.log(files);
}
```

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. No `npm install` needed and it works with `esm import` and `async/await`. For a full example, you should wrapt it in a function.

Comment: No it should not, this returns files as well as folders, which is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 7):

This is a TypeScript, optionally recursive, optionally error logging and asynchronous solution. You can specify a regular expression for the file names you want to find.

I used `fs-extra`, because its an easy super set improvement on `fs`.

```
import * as FsExtra from 'fs-extra'

/**
 * Finds files in the folder that match filePattern, optionally passing back errors .
 * If folderDepth isn't specified, only the first level is searched. Otherwise anything up
 * to Infinity is supported.
 *
 * @static
 * @param {string} folder The folder to start in.
 * @param {string} [filePattern='.*'] A regular expression of the files you want to find.
 * @param {(Error[] | undefined)} [errors=undefined]
 * @param {number} [folderDepth=0]
 * @returns {Promise<string[]>}
 * @memberof FileHelper
 */
public static async findFiles(
    folder: string,
    filePattern: string = '.*',
    errors: Error[] | undefined = undefined,
    folderDepth: number = 0
): Promise<string[]> {
    const results: string[] = []

    // Get all files from the folder
    let items = await FsExtra.readdir(folder).catch(error => {
        if (errors) {
            errors.push(error) // Save errors if we wish (e.g. folder perms issues)
        }

        return results
    })

    // Go through to the required depth and no further
    folderDepth = folderDepth - 1

    // Loop through the results, possibly recurse
    for (const item of items) {
        try {
            const fullPath = Path.join(folder, item)

            if (
                FsExtra.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory() &&
                folderDepth > -1)
            ) {
                // Its a folder, recursively get the child folders' files
                results.push(
                    ...(await FileHelper.findFiles(fullPath, filePattern, errors, folderDepth))
                )
            } else {
                // Filter by the file name pattern, if there is one
                if (filePattern === '.*' || item.search(new RegExp(filePattern, 'i')) > -1) {
                    results.push(fullPath)
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            if (errors) {
                errors.push(error) // Save errors if we wish
            }
        }
    }

    return results
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
function getFiles(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).flatMap((item) => {
    const path = `${dir}/${item}`;
    if (fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()) {
      return getFiles(path);
    }

    return path;
  });
}
```

Given the following directory:

```
dist
├── 404.html
├── app-AHOLRMYQ.js
├── img
│   ├── demo.gif
│   └── start.png
├── index.html
└── sw.js
```

Usage:

```
getFiles("dist")
```

Output:

```
[
  'dist/404.html',
  'dist/app-AHOLRMYQ.js',
  'dist/img/demo.gif',
  'dist/img/start.png',
  'dist/index.html'
]
```

Answer (score 6):

## Out of the box

In case you want an **object with the directory structure** out-of-the-box I highly reccomend you to check [directory-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree).

Lets say you have this structure:

```
photos
│   june
│   └── windsurf.jpg
└── january
    ├── ski.png
    └── snowboard.jpg
```

```js
const dirTree = require("directory-tree");
const tree = dirTree("/path/to/photos");
```

Will return:

```
{
  path: "photos",
  name: "photos",
  size: 600,
  type: "directory",
  children: [
    {
      path: "photos/june",
      name: "june",
      size: 400,
      type: "directory",
      children: [
        {
          path: "photos/june/windsurf.jpg",
          name: "windsurf.jpg",
          size: 400,
          type: "file",
          extension: ".jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: "photos/january",
      name: "january",
      size: 200,
      type: "directory",
      children: [
        {
          path: "photos/january/ski.png",
          name: "ski.png",
          size: 100,
          type: "file",
          extension: ".png"
        },
        {
          path: "photos/january/snowboard.jpg",
          name: "snowboard.jpg",
          size: 100,
          type: "file",
          extension: ".jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Custom Object

Otherwise if you want to create an **directory tree object with your custom settings** have a look at the following snippet. A live example is visible on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gifted-rubin-top5c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FgetAllFiles.js&theme=dark).

```js
// my-script.js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const isDirectory = filePath => fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory();
const isFile = filePath => fs.statSync(filePath).isFile();

const getDirectoryDetails = filePath => {
  const dirs = fs.readdirSync(filePath);
  return {
    dirs: dirs.filter(name => isDirectory(path.join(filePath, name))),
    files: dirs.filter(name => isFile(path.join(filePath, name)))
  };
};

const getFilesRecursively = (parentPath, currentFolder) => {
  const currentFolderPath = path.join(parentPath, currentFolder);
  let currentDirectoryDetails = getDirectoryDetails(currentFolderPath);

  const final = {
    current_dir: currentFolder,
    dirs: currentDirectoryDetails.dirs.map(dir =>
      getFilesRecursively(currentFolderPath, dir)
    ),
    files: currentDirectoryDetails.files
  };

  return final;
};

const getAllFiles = relativePath => {
  const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, relativePath);
  const parentDirectoryPath = path.dirname(fullPath);
  const leafDirectory = path.basename(fullPath);

  const allFiles = getFilesRecursively(parentDirectoryPath, leafDirectory);
  return allFiles;
};

module.exports = { getAllFiles };
```

Then you can simply do:

```js
// another-file.js 

const { getAllFiles } = require("path/to/my-script");

const allFiles = getAllFiles("/path/to/my-directory");
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an asynchronous recursive version.

```
    function ( path, callback){
     // the callback gets ( err, files) where files is an array of file names
     if( typeof callback !== 'function' ) return
     var
      result = []
      , files = [ path.replace( /\/\s*$/, '' ) ]
     function traverseFiles (){
      if( files.length ) {
       var name = files.shift()
       fs.stat(name, function( err, stats){
        if( err ){
         if( err.errno == 34 ) traverseFiles()
    // in case there's broken symbolic links or a bad path
    // skip file instead of sending error
         else callback(err)
        }
        else if ( stats.isDirectory() ) fs.readdir( name, function( err, files2 ){
         if( err ) callback(err)
         else {
          files = files2
           .map( function( file ){ return name + '/' + file } )
           .concat( files )
          traverseFiles()
         }
        })
        else{
         result.push(name)
         traverseFiles()
        }
       })
      }
      else callback( null, result )
     }
     traverseFiles()
    }
```

Comment: Get into the habit of adding semicolons to the end of your statements. You can't minify code otherwise. Nevertheless, thanks for the much needed async contribution.

Comment: HAHAHAHA that's not part of the spec, just some random person calling their preferred linting style "standardjs". Semicolons are good practice especially in Javascript to maintain code clarity. Otherwise you and your team must memorize the rules of [automatic semicolon insertion](https://dev.to/promhize/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascripts-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-78a), and I know at least the average JS developer where I work is not that diligent.

Comment: @user2867288 But since ASI exists, we can use it, no? I use eslint and prettier to format my code on save regularly and semicolon insertion is a non-issue.

Answer (score 5):

Took the general approach of @Hunan-Rostomyan, made it a litle more concise and added `excludeDirs` argument. It'd be trivial to extend with `includeDirs`, just follow same pattern:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

function fileList(dir, excludeDirs?) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce(function (list, file) {
        const name = path.join(dir, file);
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            if (excludeDirs && excludeDirs.length) {
                excludeDirs = excludeDirs.map(d => path.normalize(d));
                const idx = name.indexOf(path.sep);
                const directory = name.slice(0, idx === -1 ? name.length : idx);
                if (excludeDirs.indexOf(directory) !== -1)
                    return list;
            }
            return list.concat(fileList(name, excludeDirs));
        }
        return list.concat([name]);
    }, []);
}
```

Example usage:

```
console.log(fileList('.', ['node_modules', 'typings', 'bower_components']));
```

Comment: I have a main folder: scss, and inside it other folder: themes, but the final list give me all directories, not only directories without exclude directorie, whats happen?

Comment: Only works fine with '.' folder directory, with the rest directories doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use: [FS-Extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra).

```
const fileNameArray = Fse.readdir('/some/path');
```

Result:

```
[
  "b7c8a93c-45b3-4de8-b9b5-a0bf28fb986e.jpg",
  "daeb1c5b-809f-4434-8fd9-410140789933.jpg"
]
```

Comment: If i need to read sub directories I mean to say recursive then how can fs-extra is useful @LondonGuy

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up: if you're planning to perform operations on each file in a directory, try [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs) (which is used by [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), the streaming build system).

Answer (score 1):

This will work and store the result in test.txt file which will be present in the same directory

```
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(file => {
    fs.appendFileSync("test.txt", file+"\n", function(err){
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently built a tool for this that does just this... It fetches a directory asynchronously and returns a list of items. You can either get directories, files or both, with folders being first. You can also paginate the data in case where you don't want to fetch the entire folder.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-browser

This is the link, hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

No npm install. This works for the current folder where you launch the terminal, but you can change `process.cwd()` to another folder. Enjoy!

```js
const fs=require('fs');
fs.readdirSync(process.cwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a node module to automate this task: [mddir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mddir)

## Usage

node mddir "../relative/path/"

To install: npm install mddir -g

To generate markdown for current directory: mddir

To generate for any absolute path: mddir /absolute/path

To generate for a relative path: mddir ~/Documents/whatever.

The md file gets generated in your working directory.

Currently ignores node_modules, and .git folders.

## Troubleshooting

If you receive the error 'node\r: No such file or directory', the issue is that your operating system uses different line endings and mddir can't parse them without you explicitly setting the line ending style to Unix. This usually affects Windows, but also some versions of Linux. Setting line endings to Unix style has to be performed within the mddir npm global bin folder.

## Line endings fix

Get npm bin folder path with:

`npm config get prefix`

Cd into that folder

brew install dos2unix

dos2unix lib/node_modules/mddir/src/mddir.js

This converts line endings to Unix instead of Dos

Then run as normal with: node mddir "../relative/path/".

#### Example generated markdown file structure 'directoryList.md'

```
    |-- .bowerrc
    |-- .jshintrc
    |-- .jshintrc2
    |-- Gruntfile.js
    |-- README.md
    |-- bower.json
    |-- karma.conf.js
    |-- package.json
    |-- app
        |-- app.js
        |-- db.js
        |-- directoryList.md
        |-- index.html
        |-- mddir.js
        |-- routing.js
        |-- server.js
        |-- _api
            |-- api.groups.js
            |-- api.posts.js
            |-- api.users.js
            |-- api.widgets.js
        |-- _components
            |-- directives
                |-- directives.module.js
                |-- vendor
                    |-- directive.draganddrop.js
            |-- helpers
                |-- helpers.module.js
                |-- proprietary
                    |-- factory.actionDispatcher.js
            |-- services
                |-- services.cardTemplates.js
                |-- services.cards.js
                |-- services.groups.js
                |-- services.posts.js
                |-- services.users.js
                |-- services.widgets.js
        |-- _mocks
            |-- mocks.groups.js
            |-- mocks.posts.js
            |-- mocks.users.js
            |-- mocks.widgets.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm` [list-contents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-contents) module. It reads the contents and sub-contents of the given directory and returns the list of files' and folders' paths.

```
const list = require('list-contents');

list("./dist",(o)=>{
  if(o.error) throw o.error;
   console.log('Folders: ', o.dirs);
   console.log('Files: ', o.files);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If many of the above options seem too complex or not what you are looking for here is another approach using node-dir - https://github.com/fshost/node-dir

```
npm install node-dir
```

Here is a somple function to list all .xml files searching in subdirectories

```
import * as nDir from 'node-dir' ;

listXMLs(rootFolderPath) {
    let xmlFiles ;

    nDir.files(rootFolderPath, function(err, items) {
        xmlFiles = items.filter(i => {
            return path.extname(i) === '.xml' ;
        }) ;
        console.log(xmlFiles) ;       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function readFile(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

function readFolderFiles(folderPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(folderPath, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        const filePromises = files.map((file) => {
          const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file.name);
          return readFile(filePath);
        });

        Promise.all(filePromises)
          .then((fileContents) => {
            resolve(fileContents);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      }
    });
  });
}

// Usage example
const folderPath = './s3';

readFolderFiles(folderPath)
  .then((fileContents) => {
    fileContents.forEach((content, index) => {
      console.log(`File ${index + 1}:`);
      console.log(content);
      console.log('------------------');
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern (Node 21) version of the [current top listed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j/2727191#2727191) using the promise-based fs api is:

```js
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises'

const testFolder = "./tests/"

for (const file of await readdir(testFolder)) {
    console.log(file);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getFilesRecursiveSync(dir, fileList, optionalFilterFunction) {
    if (!fileList) {
        grunt.log.error("Variable 'fileList' is undefined or NULL.");
        return;
    }
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (var i in files) {
        if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            getFilesRecursiveSync(name, fileList, optionalFilterFunction);
        } else {
            if (optionalFilterFunction && optionalFilterFunction(name) !== true)
                continue;
            fileList.push(name);
        }
    }
}
```