# Print a list of all installed node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, dependencies

In a node.js script that I'm working on, I want to print all node.js modules (installed using npm) to the command line. How can I do this?

```
console.log(__filename);

//now I want to print all installed modules to the command line. How can I do this?
```

Comment: In this case, it might be useful to write a function that returns the path of the node.js modules folder (if that's possible). A cross-platform solution would be ideal.

Comment: Information about getting the list of files from a directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list npm user-installed packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) (there is even json output)

From the script:

test.js:

```
function npmls(cb) {
  require('child_process').exec('npm ls --json', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    cb(null, JSON.parse(stdout));
  });
}
npmls(console.log);
```

run:

```
> node test.js
null { name: 'x11', version: '0.0.11' }
```

Comment: Also, how can you obtain the file path of the modules folder?

Comment: path would be node_modules/[module name]. I believe this should work on all platforms. Note that this way only 'local' modules tree is printed, and `requre` looks first at node_modules, then ../node_modules, ../../node_modules ( see http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders ) and then from NODE_PATH env var

Comment: try `npm ls --parseable` for just list of paths

Answer (score 288):

If you are only interested in the packages installed globally without the full TREE then:

`npm -g ls --depth=0`

or locally (omit -g) :

`npm ls --depth=0`

Comment: I like specifying --l or --long as well, `npm -g ls --depth=0 --long`. This provides the module descriptions and github links.

Comment: if you like `npm ls` full examples check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages/40784174#40784174

Answer (score 50):

list of all globally installed third party modules, write in console:

```
 npm -g ls
```

Answer (score 29):

in any os

```
npm -g list
```

and thats it

Comment: This command will take longer than `npm -g ls --depth=0`, because it will also look for module dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, there are two ways to list out installed packages - through the Command Line Interface ([CLI](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)) or in your application using the [API](https://docs.npmjs.com/api/ls).

Both commands will print to `stdout` all the versions of packages that are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure.

---

#### CLI

```
npm list
```

Use the `-g` (global) flag to list out all globally-installed packages. Use the `--depth=0` flag to list out only the top packages and not their dependencies.

---

#### API

In your case, you want to run this within your script, so you'd need to use the API. From the docs:

```
npm.commands.ls(args, [silent,] callback)
```

In addition to printing to `stdout`, the data will also be passed into the callback.

Comment: Thanks for specifying that npm has an API accessible from applications. How do you pass arguments to the functions? I tried `npm.commands.ls(["depth=0"], ... )` but it gives me error and `npm.commands.ls(["prod"], ... )` gives me an empty array....

Answer (score 6):

Why not grab them from `dependencies` in `package.json`?

Of course, this will only give you the ones you actually saved, but you should be doing that anyway.

```
console.log(Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies));
```

Comment: That won't give you packages installed globally

Comment: The original question doesn't specify whether or not they want to include globally installed packages. This answer provides a helpful alternative to the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
for package in `sudo npm -g ls --depth=0 --parseable`; do
    printf "${package##*/}\n";
done
```

Comment: Yeah, all my Bash nowadays has `$()`

Answer (score 0):

As the end of 2021, there are few obvious way to do it, and a part as the only one give on the answer above this is a complete list.

The Node.js Documentation is actually pretty well explained regarding the matter, this is a collective list of the main commands.

All Commands will run the list of installed modules ***Locally***. In order to run global level **just add a `-g` flag at the end of the statement.**

1. See the version of all installed npm packages, **including their dependencies**.

   ```bash
   ❯ npm list

    >>> /Users/joe/dev/node/cowsay
    └─┬ cowsay@1.3.1
      ├── get-stdin@5.0.1
      ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
      │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
      │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
      ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1
      │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0
      │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
      │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
      └── strip-eof@1.0.0
   ```
2. Get only your top-level packages

   ```bash
   npm list --depth=0
   ```
3. Get the version of a specific package by specifying its name.

   ```bash
   npm list <package-name>
   ```
4. See what's the latest available version of the package on the npm repository

   ```bash
   npm view <package-name> version
   ```
5. Install an old version of an npm package using the @ syntax

   npm install @
   npm install cowsay@1.2.0

   ## Global package

   npm install -g webpack@4.16.4
6. Listing all the previous versions of a package

   ```bash
   npm view cowsay versions
   [ '1.0.0',
     '1.0.1',
     '1.0.2',
     '1.0.3',
     '1.1.0',
     '1.1.1',
     '1.1.2',
     '1.1.3',
     ....
   ]
   ```

---

### Update all the Node.js dependencies

7. Install new minor or patch release

   ```bash
    npm update
   ```
8. Install new minor or patch release but not update package.json

   ```bash
    npm update --no-save
   ```
9. To discover new releases of the packages, this gives you the list of a few outdated packages in one repository that wasn't updated for quite a while

   ```bash
     npm outdated
   ```

> Some of those updates are major releases. Running npm update won't update the version of those. Major releases are never updated in this way because they (by definition) introduce breaking changes, and npm wants to save you trouble.

To update all packages to a new major version, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

```bash
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

> This will upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file, to dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major version

---

### Dev Dependency

Install in development dependencies.

```bash
npm install <package-name> -D
npm install <package-name> --save-dev # same as above
```

Avoid installing those development dependencies in Production with

```bash
npm install --production
```

---

### Uninstalling npm packages

```bash
npm uninstall <package-name>
npm uninstall -g <package-name> # globally uninstall
```

10. Uninstall a package and ** remove the reference in the package.json**

    ```bash
      npm uninstall <package-name> -S
      npm uninstall <package-name> --save # same as above
    ```

---

Some commands with global flag examples.

```bash
npm list -g 
npm list --depth=0 -g
npm list <package-name> -g 
npm view <package-name> version -g
```

### Additional Commands

- [Answer by @prosti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784174/13903942)

### Documentation

- [Find the installed version of an npm package](https://nodejs.dev/learn/find-the-installed-version-of-an-npm-package)
- [Install an older version of an npm package](https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package)
- [Update all the Node.js dependencies to their latest version](https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version)
- [Semantic Versioning using npm](https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm)
- [Uninstalling npm packages](https://nodejs.dev/learn/uninstalling-npm-packages)
- [npm global or local packages](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages)
- [npm dependencies and devDependencies](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-dependencies-and-devdependencies)
- [The npx Node.js Package RunnerTABLE OF CONTENTS](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner)