# How to list npm user-installed packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, package-managers

How do I list the user-installed / environment package *only* in npm?

When I do `npm -g list`, it outputs every package and their dependencies. Instead I'd like to see the packages installed in the *current* working project or environment.

Comment: TL;DR; List all global: `npm list -g --depth=0` Update all global: `npm update -g`

Answer (score 1932, accepted):

```bash
npm list -g --depth=0
```

- **npm**: the Node.js package manager command line tool
- **list -g**: display a tree of every package found in the user’s folders (without the `-g` option it only shows the current directory’s packages)
- **--depth 0 / --depth=0**: avoid including every package’s dependencies in the tree view

Comment: Return empty result. My npm version is 3.6.0.

Comment: Why the `--depth=0` option is not mentioned when I run `npm help ls`?

Comment: If you install your modules at another folder using `--prefix`, then you need to add the `--prefix` too into this `npm list` command.

Comment: @Fabricio, you can run `npm config set depth 0` to make it the default.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Windows:

`C:\Web\git>npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)`

Comment: I've installed several packages, but my npm directory is empty! Bug in npm? I got warning messages on each install: `C:\Web\git>npm install --save-dev webpack
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Web\git\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Web\git\package.json'
npm WARN git No description
npm WARN git No repository field.
npm WARN git No README data
npm WARN git No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.6 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ...`

Comment: It also might be good to add `| grep -v "duped"` to remove duplicated dependencies onto the list

Comment: The following is quite fast: `find "$(npm root -g)" -maxdepth "$(<<< "$(npm root -g)" sed 's:/: :g' | wc -w)" -name package.json | cut -d/ -f5- | sed -e 's:/package.json$::' -e '/^[^@].*\//d'`. But is it correct?

Comment: @Marecky it's buried at the bottom. Look under the configuration section

Comment: can i get How i had installed i mean the command like if i had installed using `npm i -g @angular/cli` then i want to get `@angular/cli` , for all packages that i've installed?

Comment: To update all global packages run `npm update -g`  to update single `npm update -g <package>`

Answer (score 174):

You can get a list of all globally installed modules using:

```
ls `npm root -g`
```

Comment: @user2167582 On windows you would probably need something like a [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) shell for it to work.

Comment: `ls -lh \`npm root -g\`` displays them in a nice list.

Comment: That's so much better, simpler and more beautiful than the `npm list -g --depth=0` which is supposed to be the ~official~ way to do this.

Comment: This solution is much faster than the top voted one.

Comment: This solution is nice but     
`npm list -g --depth=0`  which prints out the version 
which is nice.
 Anyways, I didn't know about this command so +1 for that.

Comment: `npm root -g | gci` in Powershell on windows

Comment: @FranzSittampalam `find "$(npm root -g)" -maxdepth "$(npm root -g | sed 's:/: :g' | wc -w)" -name package.json | cut -d/ -f5- | sed -e 's:/package.json$::' -e '/^[^@].*\//d'`

Comment: @Gil more specifically a POSIX compliant shell

Answer (score 148):

**As of 13 December 2015**

[image: npm list illustration]

*While I found the accepted answer 100% correct, and useful, I wished to expand upon it a little based on my own experiences, and hopefully for the benefit of others too. (Here I am using the terms package and module interchangeably)*

In an answer to the question, yes the accepted answer would be:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

You might wish to check for a particular module installed globally, on Unix-like systems or when [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is available. This is particularly useful when checking what version of a module you are using (globally installed; just remove the `-g` flag if checking a local module):

```
npm list -g --depth=0 | grep <module_name>
```

If you'd like to see all available (remote) versions for a particular module, then do:

```
npm view <module_name> versions
```

Note, *versions* is plural. This will give you the full listing of versions to choose from.

For the latest remote version:

```
npm view <module_name> version
```

Note, *version* is singular.

To find out which packages need to be updated, you can use:

```
npm outdated -g --depth=0
```

To update global packages, you can use

```
npm update -g <package>
```

To update all global packages, you can use:

```
npm update -g
```

(However, for npm versions less than 2.6.1, please also see [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages) as there is a special script that is recommended for globally updating all packages.)

The above commands should work across NPM versions 1.3.x, 1.4.x, 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: To update a specific global package: `npm update -g <package>`. I believe `update` is preferable to `install` here because npm will be smart and do the installation only if the specified package is outdated.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit probably screentogif

Comment: @Talespin_Kit ShareX is FANTASTIC for creating and sharing gif screenshots (and any other screen shots).

Answer (score 66):

### List NPM packages with some friendly GUI!

This is what I personally prefer and it may be for others too, it may also help during presentations or meetings.

With `npm-gui` you can list local and global packages with a better visualization.

You can find the package at

- *[npm-gui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-gui)* (npm)
- *[npm-gui](https://github.com/q-nick/npm-gui)* (GitHub)

Run the following

```
// Once
npm install -g npm-gui

cd c:\your-prject-folder
npm-gui localhost:9000
```

Then open your browser at `http:\\localhost:9000`

[image: npm-gui]

Comment: how do you load for globally installed packages ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz the top menu now has a _Global_ link for globally available packages.

Comment: this is not showing my projects packages - only global? Good GUI though!

Answer (score 30):

For project dependencies use:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

For global dependencies use:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
npm ls
```

`npm list` is just an alias for `npm ls`.

For the extended information, use:

```
npm la
npm ll
```

You can always set `--depth=0` at the end to get the first level deep.

```
npm ls --depth=0
```

You can check development and production packages.

```
npm ls --only=dev
npm ls --only=prod
```

To show the info in `json` format

```
npm ls --json=true
```

The default is `false`

```
npm ls --json=false
```

You can insist on long format to show extended information.

```
npm ls --long=true
```

You can show parseable output instead of tree view.

```
npm ls --parseable=true
```

You can list packages in the global install prefix instead of in the current project.

```
npm ls --global=true
npm ls -g // shorthand
```

You can find the full documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls).

Answer (score 14):

As the end of 2021, there are few obvious way to do it. Despite all the other answers are still working, I think an update is needed besides a more defined and complete list of commands possible, and while am I at it, I added some other common commands for whom needs it (install, uninstall, etc.)

```
# Bare command
npm list
# 'ls' is an alias of list
npm ls
# Don't show dependencies
npm list --depth=0
# Global modules
npm list -g --depth=0
# More info
npm la
npm ll
# Show particular environment packages
npm ls --only=dev
npm ls --only=prod
# Parseable view (tree view)
npm ls --parseable=true
```

The Node.js documentation is actually pretty well explained regarding the matter. This is a collective list of the main commands.

Before starting, ***note:***

---

All commands will run the list of installed modules ***locally***. In order to run at the global level, **just add a `-g` flag at the end of the statement.**

---

### List installed dependency commands

1. See the version of all installed npm packages, **including their dependencies**.

   ```
   npm list

    >>> /Users/joe/dev/node/cowsay
    └─┬ cowsay@1.3.1
      ├── get-stdin@5.0.1
      ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
      │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
      │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
      ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1
      │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0
      │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
      │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
      └── strip-eof@1.0.0
   ```
2. Get only your top-level packages

   ```bash
    npm list --depth=0
   ```
3. Get the version of a specific package by specifying its name.

   ```bash
    npm list <package-name>
   ```
4. See what's the latest available version of the package on the npm repository

   ```bash
    npm view <package-name> version
   ```
5. Install an old version of an npm package using the `@` syntax

   ```
   npm install <package>@<version>
   npm install cowsay@1.2.0
   ```
6. Listing all the previous versions of a package

   ```
   npm view cowsay versions
   [ '1.0.0',
     '1.0.1',
     '1.0.2',
     '1.0.3',
     '1.1.0',
     '1.1.1',
     '1.1.2',
     '1.1.3',
     ....
   ]
   ```

---

### Update all the Node.js dependencies

7. Install a new minor or patch release

   ```bash
    npm update
   ```
8. Install a new minor or patch release, but do not update file *package.json*

   ```bash
    npm update --no-save
   ```
9. To discover new releases of the packages, this gives you the list of a few outdated packages in one repository that wasn't updated for quite a while

   ```bash
    npm outdated
   ```

> Some of those updates are major releases. Running npm update won't update the version of those. Major releases are never updated in this way, because they (by definition) introduce breaking changes, and npm wants to save you trouble.

To update all packages to a new major version, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

```bash
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

> This will upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file, to dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major version

---

### Dev Dependency

Install in development dependencies.

```bash
npm install <package-name> -D
npm install <package-name> --save-dev # The same as above
```

Avoid installing those development dependencies in production with

```bash
npm install --production
```

---

### Uninstalling npm packages

```bash
npm uninstall <package-name>
npm uninstall -g <package-name> # Globally uninstall
```

10. Uninstall a package and remove the reference in the *package.json* file

    ```bash
      npm uninstall <package-name> -S
      npm uninstall <package-name> --save # The same as above
    ```

---

Some commands with global flag examples.

```bash
npm list -g
npm list --depth=0 -g
npm list <package-name> -g
npm view <package-name> version -g
```

### Additional Commands

- [Answer by @prosti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784174/13903942)

### Documentation

- [Find the installed version of an npm package](https://nodejs.dev/learn/find-the-installed-version-of-an-npm-package)
- [Install an older version of an npm package](https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package)
- [Update all the Node.js dependencies to their latest version](https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version)
- [Semantic Versioning using npm](https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm)
- [Uninstalling npm packages](https://nodejs.dev/learn/uninstalling-npm-packages)
- [npm global or local packages](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages)
- [npm dependencies and devDependencies](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-dependencies-and-devdependencies)
- [The npx Node.js Package RunnerTABLE OF CONTENTS](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner)

Answer (score 11):

One way might be to find the root directory of modules using:

```
npm root
```

Output:

```
    /Users/me/repos/my_project/node_modules
```

And then list that directory...

```
ls /Users/me/repos/my_project/node_modules
```

Output:

```
    grunt                   grunt-contrib-jshint
```

The user-installed packages in this case are *grunt* and *grunt-contrib-jshint*.

Comment: Why not use the official built-in npm command?
`npm list -g --depth=0`

Comment: This way might help the developer understand what's going on under the hood

Comment: This isn't 100% correct.    
When I run the command `npm root`    
it tells me: `Users/me/node_modules`    
which isn't correct. My node_modules lives somewhere else.

I guess it depends on how you install node. I use `brew` to install my software. I'm guessing this is if you install node from their website using their package installer?

Comment: I think it depends on your environment variables. Check out the $NPM... vars set in your enviro. I have a custom setup, using virtualenv and the activate hook to completely rewrite $PATH from scratch depending on what the project uses.

Comment: For me, my npm broke so I couldn't use the commands. I wanted to do a full reinstall so I needed to know which packages I had installed globally to rebuild.

Comment: I am using nvm for maintaining different node versions. This is the only command that worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Node.js has a concept of *local* modules and *global* modules.

*Local module*s are located within the current project directory.

*Global modules* are generally located at the user's home directory, though we can change the path where global modules reside.

1. Lists local modules within current directory: `npm list`
2. Lists global modules: `npm list --global` OR `npm list --g`  // It will list all the top level modules with its dependencies
3. List only the top level (*installed* modules) global modules: `npm list -g --depth=0`

Answer (score 11):

>= v7.0.0:

```
npm ls -g
```

< v7.0.0:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

[Reference](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.0.0-beta.0/CHANGELOG.md):

> `npm ls` only prints the first level of dependencies by default. You can make it print more of the tree by using `--depth=<n>` to set a specific depth, or `--all` to print all of them.

For the latest release, see the npm documentation: *[npm-ls, depth](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ls#depth)*

Answer (score 9):

I use `npm -g outdated --depth=0` to list outdated versions in the global space.

Answer (score 8):

To see list of all packages that are installed.

```
$ npm ls --parseable | awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}'| sort -u
```

> show parseable of npm packages list https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls#parseable

Answer (score 8):

You can try [NPM Desktop manager](https://720kb.github.io/ndm/):

[image: NPM Desktop manager]

With just one click, you can install/uninstall packages in `dev` or `global` status.

Answer (score 7):

### Use `npm list -g` to get all the globally installed npm packages.

### To get the npm packages of the current project then you can use "npm list" only.

[image]

Comment: But that is exactly what the OP explicitly said they already knew and did not want. The question was how NOT to do that! Be sure, when answering old questions to bring new information that was not already present in one of the existing answer or the question itself.

Comment: Use npm list -g to get all the globally installed npm packages.
To get the npm packages of the current project then you can use "npm list" only.

Answer (score 6):

Folder *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* contains user-installed packages so change the directory to *node_modules* and list the items. [Core Modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html#core_Modules) are defined in Node.js's source in the `lib/` folder.

Example:

```
cd ~/node_modules
ls
```

Output:

```
     express  maxmind-native  node-whois  socket.io  ua-parser-js
     geoip    mongoskin       pdfkit      tail       zeromq
     maxmind  nodemailer      request     ua-parser  zmq
```

Answer (score 5):

For local modules, use`npm list --depth 0`.

For global modules, use `npm list -g --depth 0`.

[Example local npm module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbCka.jpg)

[Example global npm module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCk7Z.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Use `npm list` and filter by contains using `grep`

Example:

```
npm list -g | grep name-of-package
```

Answer (score 4):

As a shorthand, you can run:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using npm version 7.20.3, and it looks like the default depth is 0 already. So in my case, `npm list --global` showed only one installed package (npm). I knew I had a lot more packages installed, and I was puzzled at the output.

Eventually, I tried the `--depth` parameter and I was able to see all the packages installed: `npm list --global --depth=1` to see the other packages installed (set to say 10 to see the whole dependency tree).