# How do I check if an import statement is with an external npm packages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, eslint

Guys I'm trying to write a ESlint plugin to sort the import modules based the rules of my company and I ran into this question that I don't know how to determine if an import is an external npm package.

e.g.
`import _ from 'lodash';`
`import moment from 'moment';`

Thanks.

Comment: You could check against your current user-installed packages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages

Comment: @zfrisch thanks but I am trying to check this using JavaScript code

Comment: do you also want to check if - for example - babel, typescript etc. override node's module resolution? if you don't want to do that, you could simply check for `import moment from './moment'` (=local) or `import moment from 'moment'` (=external) (so just the `./` before the package name). We needs a bit more info.

Comment: There is a rule in eslint plugin for imports which is called `order` (https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md). You can take a look how it is implemented there