# Error: Cannot find module 'datasource-sql'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm am trying to import a module called datasource-sql

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datasource-sql

Every time I'm trying to run my project, I have this error :

```
service_1       | Error: Cannot find module 'datasource-sql'
service_1       | Require stack:
service_1       | - /code/src/MyDatabase.js
service_1       | - /code/src/server.ts
service_1       |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
service_1       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
```

I of course installed said package with `npm i datasource-sql`

Also tried `rm -rf node_module && package-lock.json && npm install`

Here is my package.json :

```json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/server",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "migration": "knex migrate:latest",
    "migration:rollback": "knex migrate:rollback --all",
    "seed": "knex seed:run",
    "init:db": "npm run migration && npm run seed",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server",
    "watch": "nodemon",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/config": "0.0.38",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.17.21",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "config": "^3.3.3",
    "datasource-sql": "^1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "knex": "^0.95.2",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Typescript",
    "GraphQL",
    "Node",
    "Javascript"
  ]
}
```

Here is the file that requires `datasource-sql` :

```js
const { SQLDataSource } = require("datasource-sql");

const MINUTE = 60;

class MyDatabase extends SQLDataSource {
  getFruits() {
    return this.knex
      .select("*")
      .from("restaurant")
      .cache(MINUTE);
  }
}

module.exports = MyDatabase;
```

The file where I'm calling it:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import config from 'config';

const MyDatabase = require("./MyDatabase");

const knexConfig = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: config.get('database'),
};

const db = new MyDatabase(knexConfig);

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Country {
    code: String
    locales: [String]
  }

  type Restaurant {
    restaurantUuid: String
    name: String
    allowReview: Boolean
    images: [String]
    country: Country
  }

  type Query {
    restaurants: [Restaurant]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
...
    ],
  },
};

const main = async () => {
  const app = express();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => ({ db })
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen({ port: config.get('server.port') }, () => console.info(
    ` Server ready and listening at ==> http://localhost:${config.get('server.port')}${
      server.graphqlPath
    }`,
  ));
};

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error('Server failed to start', error);
});
```

I suspect this being a problem tied with typescript, even if at this point I am clueless. Just in case, here is my tsconfig.json :

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "composite": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2020", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "exercise/src/**/*",
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx", "config/*",
    "exercise/src/**/*.json"]
}
```

It also may worth mentioning that I have a .nvmrc file that contains `14.15.4` at the root of my folder.

Why isn't node able to find 'datasource-sql' ?

Comment: Have you checked if the installed is really installed? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages

Comment: Another reason could be that a dependency from datasource-sql is not installed.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?