# What package versions are installed when running vite build?

Tags: vue.js, vite, build-tools

This is probably a pretty basic question, but I can't find an answer:

If I have a project with a dependency in `package.json` listed as `foobar: ^3.2.1`, what version of that dependency will be installed when I run `vite build`, assuming that the latest available version of the package is `3.4.5`?

Comment: You can check semver to understand the various ranges: https://semver.org/ Otherwise, depending of your package manager, you could run the param `list` (or alike) to know the exact version you're using.

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25497068/8816585

Comment: @kissu About the ```list``` param. If I run that command and it shows, say, ```3.3.3``` (somewhere between the version listed in ```package.json``` and the latest release), is that the version of that package that my project will build with?

Comment: Yes, you can use that tool to upgrade them and see which one you do have at the same time: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, `vite build` won't change anything to your dependencies. I won't install ones nor update them. It will only build your project (i.e. compile / transpile / minify / bundle etc.) using your source code and the code it imports (likely within the node_modules).

It will build locally, so using your local dependencies in the `node_modules` folder.

---

To check the current package version you have installed, you can run:

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep foobar
```

(The `grep` part is optional)

You can also open your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file and search for your package to know to what version your package has been fixed to.

To understand about the semantic version with npm, read this documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Comment: Supposing OP is using NPM.