# Trouble Running with React native problem with the Build "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" node_modules\yaml\dist\index.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run the build for my project. Every time I initiate the build process, I receive the following error message:

```
`ModuleLoadError: [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] require failed to load C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eas-cli\build\commands\build\index.js: Cannot find module
 »   'C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eas-cli\node_modules\yaml\dist\index.js'
 »   Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND`
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? What steps can I take to resolve this ModuleLoadError and successfully run the build for my project?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've tried various troubleshooting steps such as reinstalling the package

Comment: did you installed yaml package ?

Comment: Hello @PonmaniChinnaswamy i m not sure if i have but i m if so is their a way to uninstall ,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages

Comment: i check the file called  yaml\dist\index.js' is missing but yaml  folder is available is their a way to reinstall the above module

Comment: npm install yaml (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml)

Comment: installing yaml didn't work but i removed expo CLI and install it again and it works fine