# How to use npm to list modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use npm to list modules.

```
npm list -g
```

However it returns a very complex tree structures of installed modules.
I am wondering how to get a clean list of modules?

Comment: may be `npm -g ls --depth=0`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981938/print-a-list-of-all-installed-node-js-modules