# store folder contents (images) to var

Tags: javascript

How can I store the contents of a folder which consist entirely of images. 
I can do it this way.

```
var files = ["1.jpg","2.jpg",
             "3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg",
             "7.jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg",];
```

but I'd like to do it more dynamically I'm planning on having 100's of images in the folder.
I'm thinking something like this pseudo code

```
var images
 for i to number_of_items_in_folder
      images[i]= image_from_folder
```

The images are coming from a folder (local) called images

Comment: I think you're getting Javascript and Python mixed up..

Comment: What folder?  Where are these images coming from?  What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: The question is too vague, explain what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I assume you simply want to build an array of strings dynamically. JavaScript tutorials should cover arrays thoroughly. Have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object. Also have a look at the `for` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for. These are all basics IMO.

Comment: you can use input[type=file] with a webkitdirectory attrib to load a folder in JS. You can then loop through the input's files[] collection and push a new filename into a collection array for each image file.

Comment: People telling he is mixing things: Ever heard of pseudocode? I updated the question

Comment: It's still not clear where the code is running. If you run the code in the browser, then you cannot access the local file system.

Comment: Assuming you are on node.js, perhaps this is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on the client only you will need a trick or a hardcoded value

So

```
var images = []; 
// you tell the script how many and they all have numbers from 0 to here 87
for (var i=0; i<87; i++) {
  images.push(i+".jpg");
}
```

If you do NOT know how many you have, you need to preload them

```
var images = [],done=false,i=0; 
while (!done) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onerror=function() {
    done=true;
  }
  image.onload=function() {
    images.push(this.src);
  }
  image.src=i+".jpg";
  i++;
}
```

and if they all have different names, then you need a server script that will build the array for you.

Comment: mplungjan How can I target a specific folder? for example ' images.push(i+"/images/ .jpg");'

Comment: What if i didn't know the name of all the .jpg? ie some are called jon.jpg, trip.jpg, 3.jpg

Comment: As I wrote, you will need a server process. You cannot scan a directory in JavaScript without help from a server process