# Is there a list function for the node.js command prompt?

Tags: node.js, command-line

I'm looking for a way to list files and directories from the command line in node.js. For example in Linux there is a command ls that will list files and directories in the current directory.

Edit: No I don't mean fs.filesync. I mean a console command to list the contents of the current directory in the Node.js command prompt. Like chdir or ls or mkdir.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Comment: @Nikola that wasn't what i was asking for. I was asking for the command prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command is DIR to list all the directories and files in a directory in the nodejs command prompt window.