# Get file path in input type text instead of input type file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a textbox for user to provide file path in it, as similar to Run in Windows where user can define his relative path into the input box instead of input type="file".

Example: "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\data.csv"

After entering into the textbox "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop", user would be able to see the list of available files and directories in desktop folder so that he can choose as per his choice.

Comment: If you are referring to being able see files on the user's computer by path then you wont be able to for security reasons.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Comment: I used node.js file system **.readdir**, but when I use it on localhost then it gives me directory of my machine but when i deploy it on server then it only give me directory of server not client-side user's directory.