# indexing a directory, then save to variable? Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, indexing

How can I index a directory in nodeJS then save it to a variable?

I do not have any code to show my attempts, as I do not know what code to try.

Comment: if you are going down vote at least give a reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)

But a dumb answer is:

`var files = require('fs').readdirSync('.');`