# Programmatically import ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So instead of using

```
import A from './directory1/A'
import B from './directory1/B'
import C from './directory2/C'
import D from './directory3/D'
```

How can I programmatically write a function that reads from all the directories in my current module parent, and loads the modules inside each directory?

Comment: Does it need to be recursive (look for subfolders) ? I suggest you take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js

Comment: You can't. The main feature of ES6 modules is that they can be statically analyzed. If you need to do this dynamically, use `require` or `System.import`, depending on the setup.

Comment: _"that reads from all the directories"_ JavaScript doesn't know about directories. In which environment will the code run?