# Build a static site generator with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin, static-site

I'd like to generate html contents using javascript template literals, and output static html files on Webpack compile time. I also need a development server with hot module replacement capabilities that works with html, css, and js files.

I require *page1.js* inside [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) options:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './html-template.ejs',
  appMount: require('./src/views/page1')
})
```

Then I use a custom ejs template *html-template.ejs* to import the generated html contents:

```ejs
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMount) { %>
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMount %>
<% } %>
```

*page1.js* looks like this:

```js
const h1 = (text) => `<h1>${text}</h1>`;

module.exports = h1('Hello World');
```

Note that *page1.js* is **not** set as entry point. The only entry point is *src/index.js* (which only have a `console.log` statement inside).

When I run `webpack` everything works fine, *dist/index.html* is generated along side with *dist/main.js*.

If I run `webpack-dev-server` and try to edit *page1.js*, the browser reloads but html contents doesn't update.

Any ideas on how to make `webpack-dev-server` and Hot Module Replacement works on views files? Or do you have any other better solution to create a simple static site generator?

Comment: Maybe just use Jekyll. Or you want exactly to implement?

Comment: And also it sounds like your browser refreshes the page just before webpack has updated the view. Seems like you need to call some callback.

Comment: @DmitrySurin I don't want to use Jekyll, I want to create a static site generator with Webpack. The only problem right now is with `devServer`, and it looks like a bug to me: *page1.js* doesn't get connected to HMR correctly. I've also tried with *mini-html-webpack-plugin* and with *webpack-serve*, but the bug persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @petr answer, I confirm that require *page1.js* directly inside *html-template.ejs* works fine:

- All `require` calls inside *webpack.config.js* file are executed by **node** - *page1.js* will **not** be connected to `devServer`
- All `require` calls inside HtmlWebpackPlugin templates are executed by **webpack** - *page1.js* will be connected to `devServer` correctly

See [this](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1020#issuecomment-411644399) github issue reference.

To go even further you can create a loop to automatically load all views and generate html files:

**webpack.config.js**

- Loop through each *views* filename and load the specific *HtmlWebpackPlugin* configuration for that view

```js
const viewsFiles = require('./readViewsFiles');
const viewsConfig = require('./webpack.views');

const pages = viewsFiles.map(pageName => {
  return viewsConfig({
    title: pageName,
    path: pageName == 'page1' ? '' : pageName,
    pageName
  });
});

module.exports = pages;
```

**readViewsFiles.js**

- Return an array list of all *views* filenames without extension, for example: `['page1','page2','page3']`
- See [How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/)

**webpack.views.js**

- Return a new instance of *HtmlWebpackPlugin*
- If `path == ''` then `filename: 'index.html'` otherwise `filename: 'page2/index.html'` (and so on for every *views* name)

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = ({
  path = '',
  template = './html-template.ejs',
  title,
  pageName
} = {}) => ({
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${path && path + '/'}index.html`,
      template,
      title,
      pageName
    })
  ]
});
```

**html-template.ejs**

- Dynamically loads the correct *views* file

```ejs
<%= require(`./src/views/${htmlWebpackPlugin.options.pageName}.js`) %>
```

**page1.js** and other similar views files

```
const h1 = (text) => `<h1>${text}</h1>`;

module.exports = h1('Hello World');
```

When you run `webpack` the structure in the *dist* folder for html files will looks like this:

```
dist
│    index.html
│
│--- page2
│         index.html
│
│--- page3
          index.html
```

The *dist* folder is considered the root of your server.

Now you can implement a router in your app to navigate between pages:

- Set a link to `/` for page1: `http://www.mywebsite.com/`
- Set a link to `/page2` for page2: `http://www.mywebsite.com/page2`

Note: you don't have to add *index.html* to your links to navigate between pages. With this method you'll not see *.html* extension at the end of the url.

Note: you can't view your app via `file:///` protocol because your router links are set as **absolute path**, you must use a local or a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in html:

```
<%=require('./views/page1.js')%>
```

Comment: Thanks, this help solve the problem. I'd like to know why require *page1.js* inside *HtmlWebpackPlugin* options doesn't connect it to HMR, seems like a bug.