# having trouble parsing JSON key value pair by looping over a file directory with npm script

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a key value pair which looks like this

```
{
    'static/default/js/index': './app_main/js/index.js',
    'static/default/js/util': './app_util/js/util.js'
}
```

with path of the output file as the key and the source as the value.

The problem is when I debug the script at loop where I am iterating through the directory I see the correct key value pair as expected. But when I try to view it outside the loop it returns an empty object. Here is how my directory structure looks like

[image]

And here is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = [
    {
        type: 'js',
        inputPath: [
            './app_util/js/',
            './app_main/js/'
        ],
        outputPath: 'dist/static/default/js'
    }
];

function getFilePath(path) {
    var out = {};
    path.forEach(obj => {
        obj.inputPath.forEach(dirNname =>{
            fs.readdir(dirNname, (err, fileNames) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
                    return;
                }
                fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
                    out[obj.outputPath] = dirNname+fileName;    
                    console.log(out); // eslint-disable-line no-console
                });
            })
        })
    })
    return out;
}

var x = getFilePath(path);
//this returns an empty object
console.log(x); // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Feels like I am missing something simple

Comment: I hope, forEach is not asynchronous. if it is async, you may need to use and attach promise handler.

Comment: readdir is async, you can use readdirSync instead. Or handle the promise.

Comment: @ngearing -- if I use readdirSync I get 
TypeError: "options" must be a string or an object
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:943:11)

Comment: Sure, readdirSync isnt a drop in replacement, it returns and array so you dont need the callback. eg.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = [
  {
    type: 'js',
    inputPath: [
      './app_util/js/',
      './app_main/js/'
    ],
    outputPath: 'dist/static/default/js'
  }
];

function getFilePath(path) {
  var out = {};
  path.forEach(obj => {
    obj.inputPath.forEach(dirNname => {

      var fileNames = fs.readdirSync(dirNname)
      fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
        out[obj.outputPath] = dirNname + fileName;
        console.log(out); // eslint-disable-line no-console
      });

    })
  })
  return out;
}

var x = getFilePath(path);
//this returns an empty object
console.log('final result is: ', x); // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

I used readdirSync. This works fine.