# Importing vs requiring large amounts of image files in React Native and saving it to state

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

In my React Native app I'm trying to import 52 png image files from a resource folder. But the * symbol that is be used to import all files in React is not recognized in ReactNative I guess. So I'm nesting loops to create regexs to directly import all 52 images. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727191/13700347