# Is there any directory walker in ts / js using an async iterator?

Tags: typescript, async-iterator, filewalker

I found plenty of walkers on npm but none is using an asynchronous iterator.
Most of them are either using a callback or a promise leading to memory leaks on huge directories.

Is there any recent library using the following pattern:

```
async function* walk(dirPath) {
    // some magic…
    yield filePath;
}
```

To then use it like:

```
for await (const filePath of walk('/dir/path')) {
    console.log('file path', filePath);
}
```

Comment: Library recommendations are, as you should know by now, off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I simply made this walker using the synchronous readdir, it is very fast and memory efficient, I listed 2.5 millions of entries in around 3 minutes without any memory leak.

```
import path from 'path';
import fs, {Dirent} from 'fs';

function* walk(path:string):IterableIterator<string> {

    const entries:Dirent[] = fs.readdirSync(path, {withFileTypes: true});

    for (const entry of entries) {
        const entryPath:() => string = () => `${path}/${entry.name}`;

        if (entry.isFile()) {
            yield entryPath();
        }

        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            yield* walk(entryPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
for (const path of walk(directoryPath)) {
    console.log(path);
}
```