# Unable to create new folder using Desktop App using Electron JS

Tags: javascript, electron, fs

It works properly when I run the same code locally using Electron JS.

```
var dir = './test-new-folder'; // OR var dir = 'test-new-folder';

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
   fs.mkdirSync(dir, '0777', true);
}
```

The above code works properly in my local and creates a folder named 'test-new-folder' inside my root folder.

But after creating it's desktop application on MAC,

1. Why this code doesn't work? Why doesn't it create 'test-new-folder'? What could be the work around for this?
2. Also I want to track/get all the data which will be pushed in this newly created folder! Can I get such events? Or any suggestions for this?

Comment: You cant use `./` as its relative to the packaged app not your cwd, instead use getPath https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! And yes as you said, it's right!!!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Can you please tell me if theres a way to track as per my 2nd question mentioned!

Comment: For 2. you can use fs.readDir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j

Comment: Was thinking kinda same way as I've FS with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @lawrence Cherone in the comments, I've followed this: [electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname)

And the solution I've got is below,

```
var desktopPath = (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath('desktop');

var dir = desktopPath + '/test-new-folder';

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
   fs.mkdirSync(dir, '0777', true);
}
```