# Listing files in folder in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a vscode extension that does some custom auto-completing of files paths.

I want to take what the user has typed, and if that value resolves to a folder in the workspace, I want to list all the files in that folder for auto-complete.

For example, given:

- a workspace located at: /home/me/my-vs-project
- with files:

  - /home/me/my-vs-project/assets/dog.png
  - /home/me/my-vs-project/assets/cat.jpeg

If I type in 'assets' or './assets' into vscode, the extension should be able to provide me an autocomplete list of:

- './assets/dog.png'
- './assets/cat.png'

Here's a snippet of the code that doesn't work (returns 0 results)..

```
let inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder = getInput(document, position); // for example, would return: '/home/me/my-vs-project/assets' for input of './assets'

let glob = inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder + '/*';

vscode.workspace.findFiles(glob, null, 100).then((uris: vscode.Uri[] ) => {         
   uris.forEach((uri: vscode.Uri) => {              
         console.log(uri);
   });
});
```

For some reason, the above code is returning 0 uris though. Thoughts on how I have to format the glob to make this happen? and/or if there is a better approach?

Comment: Since you are working using Node you can just choose from any of these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j

Answer (score 0):

I think you wronged the glob.
I found this intresting [wiki](https://github.com/ev3dev/vscode-ev3dev-browser/wiki/Glob-Patterns) about Glob pattern composition.

```
        let inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder = 'asset'; // for example, would return: '/home/me/my-vs-project/assets' for input of './assets'

        //https://github.com/ev3dev/vscode-ev3dev-browser/wiki/Glob-Patterns
        let glob = '**/'+inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder+'/*.*';//or +'/{*.png,*.jpeg}';
```

Or you can use the node built-in fs

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
        fs.readdir(inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder, (err, files: string[]) => {
            files.forEach((file: path) => {
                const uri = vscode.Uri.file(file);
                console.log(uri);
            });
        });
```

More simple, if you want to get all the files in the asset folder and don't want to filter for extension.

Comment: Hi! In your vs Glob example, wouldn't that find all files in ANY folder named 'asset' in the workspace? I want to have a glob that will only find files that are direct children of the folder.

Comment: Yes, I think you just missed the extension glob part. Ie : in ` let glob = inputAsWorkspaceRelativeFolder + '/*';` the ending '/*' should be '/*.*' or better '/*.png,jpeg,jpg,gif}'

Comment: Looking at the deprecated `vscode.workspace.rootPath` :
When there is just one folder open, that folder is taken as the workspace root, 
but  when you have more folders/workspaces loaded you can only search using relative pattern, because you have no more a root path available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using `vscode.RelativePattern` -- I'm sure I could've done it using generic GlobPatterns but im still not clear what the `findFiles(..)` consider the 'root' when matching files; RelativePattern is *explicitly* relative to the workspace root.

```
let workspaceFolder: vscode.WorkspaceFolder | undefined = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(document.uri);

        if (!workspaceFolder || document.isUntitled) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // Workspace folder: /home/me/my-project
        let workspaceFolderPath: string = workspaceFolder.uri.path;

        let relativeSearchFolderPrefix = path.normalize(path.dirname(document.uri.path) + '/' + searchText);
        relativeSearchFolderPrefix = path.relative(workspaceFolderPath, relativeSearchFolderPrefix);

            let relativePattern: vscode.RelativePattern = new vscode.RelativePattern(
                workspaceFolderPath,
                relativeSearchFolderPrefix + '/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,gif}');

return vscode.workspace.findFiles(globPattern, null, 50).then((uris: vscode.Uri[] ) => {            
            let relativePaths: string[] = [];

            uris.forEach((uri: vscode.Uri) => {             
                relativePaths.push(path.relative(current, uri.path));
            });

            // trivial custom function that turns an array of strings into CompletionItems
            return getCompletionItems(relativePaths, vscode.CompletionItemKind.File);
        });
```

Comment: I think you are expert in VS Code

Comment: @empire29 Do you have a github repo for your extension in js? I'm writing an extension in which I'm struggling to do this exact in js.