# NodeJS : Always keep 30 latest files in folder, delete the rest?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to keep some backups in a folder. I want to keep a backup of 30 JSONs at any time, JSONs are being added hourly. If the number of files in the folder is > 30 I want to delete the older files. Is this possible with nodejs?

This is what I've got so far:

```
ipcMain.on("BACKUP_TO_DISK", function(event, arg) {    
    var date = new Date();
    var json = JSON.stringify(arg);
    fs.writeFile("./backup/" + date.yyyymmddhh()+ "_" + arg.prefix + "_backup.json", json, "utf8", function() {
      console.log("Successfully Saved.");
    });
  });
```

and its being called from my React app like so:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      var data = this.props.data.get("data");
      var prefix = this.props.preferences.get("savePrefix");
      var counter = this.props.data.get("counter");
      var path = this.props.preferences.get("path");

      console.log("BACK")
      this.props.backupToDisk(data, prefix, counter, path);  
    }, 60000 * 30 ); //every half an hour
```

Comment: can you show code that is adding those JSONs ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But the question is too broad. Have you tried anything? What was the problem?

Comment: @Jake11 added the code!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use filesystem to do that. 
These two should be enough to build such thing:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp
[How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j)