# How to check the directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a piece of code that checks for the presence of `.json`. I need the code to look for `.json` only in a specific folder. How can I do it?

```
if (extName === '.json') { 
    const fullFileNamed = '../../theme-default/resource/i18n'
    // console.log (fullFileNamed, "fullFileNamed")

    if(fullFileNamed) {
      console.log ( fullFileNamed, "fullFileNamed")
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')
      console.log (fileContent, "fileContent")
    } 
}
```

this if is not correct. how to do it right?

Comment: I think this will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j

Comment: you need to correct the variable name `fullFileNamed` in the line `const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')`

Comment: do you want to check for the json file and print content of that file

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition is fine, the variable name is misspelled in `const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')` and it should be corrected to `const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileNamed, 'utf8')`

```
if (extName === '.json') { 
    const fullFileNamed = '../../theme-default/resource/i18n'
    // console.log (fullFileNamed, "fullFileNamed")

    if(fullFileNamed) {
      console.log ( fullFileNamed, "fullFileNamed")
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileNamed, 'utf8')
      console.log (fileContent, "fileContent")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fs.access(path[, mode], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback), the optional `mode` argument can be used to check the accessibility of the file, for example `fs.constants.F_OK` check if the file exists and `fs.constants.R_OK` indicates that the file is readable. [(The full list of File Access Constants)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_access_constants)

```
if (extName === '.json') { 
        const fullFileNamed = '../../theme-default/resource/i18n';
        // console.log (fullFileNamed, "fullFileNamed")
        // Check if the file exists in the current directory, and if it is readable.
        fs.access(fullFileNamed, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(`${fullFileNamed} ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is not readable'}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`${fullFileNamed} exists, and it is readable`);
            const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileNamed, 'utf8');
            console.log ('fileContent', fileContent);
          }
        });
}
```

For synchronous tests use [`fs.accessSync(path[, mode])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode):

```
try {
  fs.accessSync(fullFileNamed, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.R_OK);
  console.log(`${fullFileNamed} exists, and it is readable`);
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileNamed, 'utf8');
  console.log ('fileContent', fileContent);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`${fullFileNamed} ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is not readable'}`);
}
```