# Get all images and its relative path from folder

Tags: node.js

I have couple of images in `images/source` directory which is at root level. I want to read all the images in the folder and get its path to something like below:

```
var images = ['images/source/first.jpg', 'images/source/second.png', 'images/source/third.png'];
```

I am trying to read the directory something like below, but its not working!

```
const imgPath= fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '/images/source')).sort();
```

The above code reads all the images, but i need all the images with their path in an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j)

Comment: const imgPath= fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '/images/source')).sort().map(e => `images/source/${e}`)
just map the array?

Answer (score 0):

Read this forum. It may helpful.

[How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j)

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```